# How to convert IDictionary<object,string> to ParseObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, casting, cloud

I have defined a ParseObject subclass called LeaderboardScore, which is returned from my cloud code function as an `IDictionary<string, object>`.

I was hoping that I could just do something like in the example below, but the cast fails :(

**Failed attempt to cast:**

```
ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>("getScore", parameters).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    LeaderboardScore score = t.result as LeaderboardScore;
    Debug.Log(score.get<string>("facebookId"));
}
```

**LeaderboardScore Definition:**

```
[ParseClassName("LeaderboardScore")]
public class LeaderboardScore : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("facebookId")]
    public string FacebookId
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>("FacebookId"); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value, "FacebookId"); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("score")]
    public int Score
    {
        get { return GetProperty<int>("Score"); }
        set { SetProperty<int>(value, "Score"); }
    }
}
```

Note that t.Result does have the correct information, meaning I can access it by calling things like `t.Result["facebookId"] as string`, but it would be much nicer to be able to pass around a LeaderboardScore object instead of an `IDictionary<string, object>`.

If anyone could shed some light on this issue I would greatly appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to create [native subclasses](http://docs.parseplatform.org/dotnet/guide/#subclassing-parseobject) for each of the ParseObjects you are interested in, then having your cloud function return that type or list of that type like so:

```
ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<LeaderboardScore>("getScore", parameters).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    LeaderboardScore score = t.Result;
}
```

Parse takes care of the conversion so you don't have to worry about it. To return a list, simply use `IList<LeaderboardScore>`

Answer (score 1):

You can cast all dictionary to object(with property) by:

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this IDictionary<string, object> source)
    where T : class, new()
{
    T someObject = new T();
    Type someObjectType = someObject.GetType();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in source)
    {
        someObjectType.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(someObject, item.Value, null);
    }

    return someObject;
}
```

Comment: Hey, that is a pretty cool utility function, but unfortunately it doesn't really work with ParseObjects :(  

I tried to modify it a little to get it to work, but I had no luck:
http://pastebin.com/SvVgdVvL  

It tells me "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the `someObjectType.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(someObject, item.Value, null);` line.  

I feel like there must be an easier way to do this with Parse since it would be such a common operation, but I can't find any examples or any mention of it in the documentation.

Comment: try to use:
`var property = someObjectType.GetProperty(item.Key);
if (property != null) 
{
    property.SetValue(someObject, item.Value, null);
}`

Comment: if your dict have "facebookId" you must have the same name field in class

Comment: I am now able to get this partially working by changing the property names of LeaderboardScore to camel case which matches the values my Parse cloud function returns.

It works for all properties except 'score', which throws a 'failed to convert parameters' exception. Any idea why that might be happening?



New code: http://pastebin.com/c0ghReGt